# Failure trace window for junit 3 doesn't show expected values

Tags: java, android, eclipse, junit

I'm executing some JUnit test cases with the Android SDK, and I've found that none of the assertEquals are showing their expected values in the log.

Here is an example assertion.

```
assertEquals("mocks", model.getUseTable());
```

Here is the failure exception.

```
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: expected:<...k...> but was:<......>
at ca.thinkingmedia.gems.test.models.AbstractModelTest.test_Auto_Table_Name(AbstractModelTest.java:17)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:545)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1575)
```

As you can see the *expected* values are masked with dots. This is making it very time consuming to figure out what wrong values were checked.

Is there a way to have these values shown correctly in the exception messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
final String actual = model.getUseTable()
assertEquals("Expecting mocks but was " + actual, "mocks", actual);
```

and the message will be in the log.

Comment: I guess there is no other way. Is this an Android issue, or do all JUnit tests do this?

Comment: Creating my own test class that overrides assertEquals(x,y) and adds "x" to the reason message seems to be the easiest trick.